# Check if value is set into PHP array's elements

Tags: php, arrays, element

I have the following array called `$users`:

```
$users [2 elements]
0: 
(array) [4 elements]
id: (string) "5"
user_id: (null) 5
email: (string) "test@test.com"
activated: (integer) 0 

1: 
(array) [4 elements]
id: (string) "6"
user_id: (null) 6
email: (string) "test1@test.com"
activated: (integer) 1
```

I want to display something in HTML only if any of array's elements have `activated` set to 1. Can be all, can be only one.

I tried with `if( in_array(['actived'] == 1, $users))` with no success.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it while you're iterating the array in the loop

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($user['activated'] === 1) {
        // echo html here
    }
}
```

Or squeezed inside an html markup:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <?php if ($user['activated'] === 1): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user['email']; ?></td> // and others
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or you could filter out all items inside using `array_filter`:

```
$filtered_users = array_filter($users, function($user) {
    return $user['activated'] === 1; // get all user with activated key with value 1
});
```

Of course, if it came from mysql db, it would be better just to use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT id, user_id, email, activated FROM users WHERE activated = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix it before reading it here by doing a loop in my controller and export a variable (pretty much your first solution). Then, in my view, I just check if that var is set and display the content I want.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_column()` to get all `activated` values and search in them:

```
if (in_array(1, array_column($users, 'activated'), true))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `if($users->activated == 1)`